# How to insert numeric text into the image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, plot

I'm using R2011a Matlab version.I need to insert numeric values on image.
I referred this [link](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/26033-how-to-insert-text-into-image), but in that link,they only mentioned how to insert *text* on the image.
This [answer](http://in.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/inserttext.html) is also not working for my Matlab version.

Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, text and numeric values are not *differetnt*: you can convert any numeric value into a text (string) using [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html):

```
 numeric = 10.453;
 as_text = sprintf('%.3f', numeric);
```

Now you have a *text* `'10.453'` you can put on the image.

---

Alternatively, you can

```
 img = imread('football.jpg');
 fh = figure;
 imshow(img, 'border', 'tight');
 text( 'Position', [30, 50, 0], 'String', sprintf('%.3f', numeric), 'Color', 'w');
```

You get:
[image]

See [`text`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) for more information and options for formatting the text on top of the image.

If you want to actually *save* the altered pixel values (representing the text on top of the image) you can capture the figure using [`getframe`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html):

```
fr = getframe(fh);
image_with_text = fr.cdata;
```

Comment: in the above code,i dont need to pop up the image ,i only need to save it,but when I remove this  `imshow(img, 'border', 'tight');` , its giving a graph.cant I remove the "imshow" part?

Comment: @temp you need to imshow the image in order to render the text on top of it. I believe you can find a figure option to have this done in the background